# Can I use Ruby Cucumber Watir to Solve a Key Pass to URL puzzle?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am a NEWBIE. Any help is appreciated.

I've been given the challenge of automating a Key Pass challenge.

a URL is provided (this is an example, I don't think the creator of the challenge wants it in public): www.guessmypasskey.com

When you visit the site, the body text simple returns, Key Denied:

If you add the following path, www.guessmypasskey/?key=a the site will return: Key Denied:00

The key is only alphanumeric and of unknown length...through manual testing I was able to find the key by determining that the binary code returns meant the following: 00 not a character used, 01 character used, wrong position, 11 correct character, correct position.

I envision, opening a browser to the URL with watir, checking a-a, A-Z, 0-9, in the first position...if 00 is displayed on page, delete character from possibility, if 01 is present write the number to a file (this will determine the character length needed.

Basic question, Am I going the wrong direction? Trying to automate with Ruby Cucumber Watir?

I know additional steps will be needed t determine the order of the characters....I'm just trying to get started on the first step, confirming the validity of the characters and the length of the pass key.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of disappointed that the URL the real one. =p

Anyways, that approach would work... but I would imagine it being massive overkill.

Instead, what I would do is simply create a simple Node.js script (using JavaScript) which basically just loops through all possible combinations for each character, stepping through as you move.

You can just use the simple "request" module to request the web page. Then just build up your string like that.

```
var request = require('request');

// Gets content of one call... add this to your loop somehow.
request({uri: 'http://guessmypasskey.com?key=' + key}, function (err, response, body) {
   // body has the result to check
});
```

This is probably going to be infinitely easier than setting up the tech stack you were talking about... not to mention a lot faster.

Your general approach (ignoring technology) sounds pretty spot on.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for...I suspected I was over complicating. uri is a gem within Ruby so making a version of your proposal should be very possible.